# Getting values as array from SQL Database and performing a search operation based on that array

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to get a couple of array from my database based on WHERE condition and need to perform a search from another table based on that array. I'm trying to do that, however I'm getting couple of errors.

The code is:

```
 $sql = "SELECT post_id FROM flat_booking where buyer_mobile='$mobile'";
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
 $post_id = array();
 while(($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))) {
 $post_id[] = $row['id'];    
 }


 $sql = "SELECT id,area,furnished,image,numberofrooms,price,type FROM flatowner where id IN '$post_id'";
```

Maybe this line is throwing the error:

```
$post_id[] = $row['id'];
```

Comment: *I'm getting couple of errors* - What errors are being thrown?

Comment: Probably _undefined index 'id'_ since the column is _post_id_.

Comment: try imploding the array in the sql, `$sql = "SELECT id,area,furnished,image,numberofrooms,price,type FROM flatowner where id IN (".implode(',',$post_id).")";`

Answer (score 0):

You can try using JOINS to reduce the amount of query you have to execute and also bypass having to pass in comma separated list in subsequent query.  Try something like the query below.

```
SELECT
  O.id,
  O.area,
  O.furnished,
  O.image,
  O.numberofrooms,
  O.price,
  O.type
FROM flatowner O
  INNER JOIN flat_booking B ON O.id = B.post_id
WHERE B.buyer_mobile = '$mobile'
```